# prepareForSegue is not being called from a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am implementing multiple collection views in a single view controller. It's working fine. In the collection view, when I call the didSelect method, I have to pass the ID to the next view controller. I used `prepareForSegue` but it's not calling.

This is the code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == self.FirstCollectionview
    {
    }
    else
    {
        let index : Int = indexPath.row
        let idvalues = info[index].category_id
        print("values",idvalues as Any)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DATA", sender: self)
    }
}

func prepareForsegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject) {
    if segue.identifier == "DATA" {
        let detailsview = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController
        detailsview?.id = sender as! String
        print("sendervalue",sender as Any)
    }else
    {
        print("not this ")
    }
}
```

This is the second view controller:

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    var iddata : String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("IDValues",iddata as Any)
    }
```

The value of IDValues is empty.
How do I pass the id to the next view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature is not correct. It should look like as below,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

}
```

Comment: @kamaran Tq very much u save my time its working fine